# preview image before uploading

Tags: html, flash, file-upload

I'm looking for some flash based plug-in which allows me to display an image as soon as the user selects it in the file dialog.

I looked at swfupload but couldn't find any way to display the image selected.. no handle on file path or contents as far as I could find.

Anyone knows how to do this? Or some other plug-in which does this?

Comment: This is a one-liner to do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27002935/1317040

Answer (score 1):

These two will probably do the trick:

- http://code.google.com/p/image-upload-preview/
- http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread114822.html

Comment: First link is as far as I see it pretty spot on

Comment: It's only compatible with IE and firefox. I already have it working for IE and firefox. In IE I can retrieve the path of the file and in firefox I have the FileReader API. I need a cross platform solution.